# jquery change background on slide

Tags: jquery, css, background-color, onchange

I want to change the background of an div on the on the current image slide.

So on slide 1 = background: blue
On slide 2 = background: green

I think is have the make a script like: 
if slide 1 == current-sr-slide-visible
change this css.

Someone an idea how to do this?

Comment: why don't you put the background colors in styles for those slides. like create some classes like `.blue{background:blue;} .green{background:green;}` now add to the specific slides you wanted.

Comment: It a div(business hours) in the slide. Its position in above the slide and stays at that position.
So first slide is a image with a blue filter.
second slide is a image with a green filter.
On slide the div business hours has to change color. I don't want to change the back ground on click but when the slide is active(automatic) do this.

Comment: unclear what you're asking

Comment: I have an image slider, i have positioned an div in this slider. So the div stays at the position while the slider automatic slides the images. Now i want to change the background of the div in the slider when the image slider show a new image.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are not showing any code, I assume:

- All the slides have the same CSS class `slide`
- The current slide has additionally the class 'active-slide'

Then, you don't need jquery, you can just write with css:

```
.slide{
  background:blue;
} 

.slide.active{
  background:green!important;
}
```

**EDIT**

You can try this:

```
 var slide_color = $(".active.slide").css('backgroundColor'); // get the current slide color

$(".div").css('backgroundColor', slide_color ); // set the color to the div.
```